# Css position scrollbar on page

Tags: html, css

I want to position the scrollbar somewhere else on the page, and make it have a set height, instead of 100% (example like 400px)

[image: (Example Image)]

I want to position it approx at that spot, with that width
It works if I add padding/margin and position to the body, but it destroys the rest of the website object's position

Example:

```css
 html {
        overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical; 
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    body {
     overflow-y: scroll;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 12px;
    }
     
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
        -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }
     
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
        border-radius: 10px;
     
        background-image: url(http://www.lovethisgif.com/uploaded_images/121722-File-color-Square-Cm.gif-Wikimedia-Commons.gif); 
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
    }
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
     background: rgba(255,0,0,0.4); 
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to share your working code.

Comment: Why would you need a html code? It's scrollbar, it's not included in html, it's used as a part of webkit -.-

Comment: Just use custom scroll bar.. its much effective and customizable i think

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would create a fixed-sized DIV, place that into the `body` (which gets 100% width and 100% height), put all content into that DIV and give it `overflow-y : scroll` or `auto`